# Where are babel plugins stored on react tree? After npm install, plugin not in project tree

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader, optional-chaining

I'm not understanding why some babel packages appear within my node_modules, while others do not.
I have

```
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.16.5",
```

in my babel.config.js in the root of the project tree.
I did

```
npm i --save @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

but the plugin does not appear in my tree afterwards.
It does appear in package.json under dev-dependencies, and I added it under dependencies too, followed by npm install.

Any idea why this package seems to install correctly but does not appear in my tree ?

Comment: What do you mean by "tree"? Do you mean that you are not seeing this module inside node_modules?

Comment: I did a find from the root of the project, which is above node_modules in the hierarchy, so that node_modules is traversed by the find.